# Making a background image change on scroll JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make the background image on my page's body change after the page has been scrolled past a certain point. I can get the initial change, but then if you scroll back up the first background image is still replaced. I am still pretty new to JavaScript and would appreciate any help on this!

```
function changeCss () {
  var body = document.querySelector("body");
  if (this.scrollY > 1000) { document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../../../img/upa/landing/images/bg.jpg)" 
}  else { document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../../../img/upa/landing/images/bg-2.jpg)";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss , false);
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function changeCss () {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = this.scrollY > 1000
     ? "url(../../../img/upa/landing/images/bg.jpg)"
     : "url(../../../img/upa/landing/images/bg-2.jpg)";
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss , false);
```

Generaly in else case You need to change **backgroundImage**, in place of **display**

Comment: Whoops, I did have the "backgroundImage" on there when I was messing around before asking the question. I appreciate the answer! This script's behavior replaces the body image before the point of the scroll event.

Comment: Do you need to have some initial image, after change it on scroll bottom, after change it with third image on scroll top? Or you need to keep initial image on scrolling to the top (scrollY < 1000)?

Comment: Script in the answer unequivocally will change body bg image to bg.jpg when scrollY is more than 1000. So maybe you need something else?)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have it switch back to the initial image that is set when scrolling back up the page. That image is bg-2.

Comment: So script in answer works for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  It changes to bg.jpg immediately on scroll and does not change back.

Comment: It means that the problem is somewhere else, maybe you are mutating scroll position, which causes it to be always greather than 1000, or something like so

Comment: When I leave off the ternary and don't try to set the second image, the scroll behavior works as it should. But that leaves me where I started, needing the original content.

Comment: I was able to get it working with this: 

function changeCss () {
  var bg1 = document.querySelector("#custom-body");
  this.scrollY > 1000 ? bg1.style.backgroundImage = "url(../../../img/upa/landing/images/bg.jpg)" : bg1.style = "initial";
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss , false);

Comment: Got it, you actually needed to switch bg on custom body not on real.